# Does Iterable#iterator() return a new iterator or an existing one?

Tags: java, iterator, iterable

Does calling `anIterable.iterator()` return a new or an existing Iterator? Does it depend on the Iterable implementation?

More specifically, would the following code work as expected (i.e. the inner loop would iterate from the beginning)?

```
for (Item itemA : items) {
    for (Item itemB : items) {
        ....
    }
}
```

If not, than how can this be achieved on an `Iterable`?

Answer (score 2):

**Iterable**

`Iterable` is the `Interface`, we need to provide implementation for [iterator()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) method.

```
public class MyCollection<E> implements Iterable<E>{

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new MyIterator<E>();
    }
}
```

Implementation skeleton of the `MyIterator` class:

```
public class MyIterator <T> implements Iterator<T> {

    public boolean hasNext() {

        //implement...
    }

    public T next() {
        //implement...;
    }

    public void remove() {
        //implement... if supported.
    }
}
```

Using `MyCollection` generified, and with the new for-loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyCollection<String> stringCollection = new MyCollection<String>();

    for(String string : stringCollection){

    }
}
```

For your 2nd question, output speaks, the inner loop will loop from the starting everytime.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        names.add("a1");
        names.add("a2");

        for (String itemA : names) {
            for (String itemB : names) {
                System.out.println("Inner => " + itemB);
            }
            System.out.println("Outer => " + itemA);
        }
    }

Inner => a1
Inner => a2
Outer => a1
Inner => a1
Inner => a2
Outer => a2
```

Refereed [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-generics/implementing-iterable.html) for examples

Answer (score 2):

`Iterable<T>` is an interface, so there is no default implementation.

In `ArrayList<T>` for instance, the `iterator<E>` method will return a new instance of the nested class `Itr` each invocation:

```
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new Itr();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`anIterable.iterator()` should return a new iterator and in that case the nested enhanced for loops will work as expected. All standard implementations of `Iterable` return a new Iterator when `iterator()` is called.

If some bad implementation of the Iterable interface doesn't return a new Iterator in consecutive calls to `iterator()`, the nested enhanced for loops will break.

BTW, the Javadoc of `Iterable`'s `iterator()` method doesn't require that it return a new Iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Depends how iterable interface is implemented. Generally the collection frameworl classes returns new instance.

Answer (score 0):

You may iterate the same collection in parallel, but you cannot modify it. So your code is completely correct: the new `iterator` would be returned each time.